# Suitescript: copying sublist data from one record to another

Tags: suitescript2.0

I have a before load user event function on an invoice record that create a button called 'create vendor bill'.

When this button is pressed, a new vendor bill record is opened. The UE script:

```js
    /**
     *@NApiVersion 2.x
     *@NScriptType UserEventScript
     */
    define([
      "N/url",
      "N/record",
      "N/runtime",
      "N/ui/serverWidget",
      "N/redirect",
    ], function (url, record, runtime, serverWidget, redirect) {
      var exports = {};
    
      /**
       * @param {UserEventContext.beforeLoad} context
       */
      function beforeLoad(context) {
        if (
          context.type == context.UserEventType.EDIT ||
          context.type == context.UserEventType.VIEW
        ) {
          var record = context.newRecord;
          var recordId = record.id;
          var recordType = record.type;
          var customer = record.getValue({ fieldId: "entity" });
          log.debug("entity", customer);
          var scriptObj = runtime.getCurrentScript();
          var customForm = scriptObj.getParameter({
            name: "custscript_custom_form_vb",
          });
          var recordSublist = record.getSublist({ sublistId: "item" });
          log.debug("item", recordSublist);
    
       
          var form = context.form;
          log.debug("form", form);
          
         
    
          var userVarStr = record;
          log.debug("uservarstr", userVarStr);
    
          var userVarURL = url.resolveRecord({
            recordType: "vendorbill",
            params: {
              entity: parseInt(customer),
              supportcase: recordId,
              cf: parseInt(customForm),
          
            },
          });
    
          
    
          form.addButton({
            id: "custpage_button_test",
            label: "Create Vendor Bill",
            functionName: "getDetails('" + userVarURL + "')",
          });
    
         
        }
      }
    
      exports.beforeLoad = beforeLoad;
      return exports;
    });
```

Once the page redirects to the vendor bill form, a client script (deployed on the form), sets the field values on the body of the vendor bill using the parameters passed in the url

This is working as expected.

Where I am getting stuck is trying to work out how to pass the 'item' sublist values to from the invoice to the vendor bill?

Would I pass this as an array?

From what I understand, there is a limit to the number of characters that can be passed via the url.
I can't find anything online or in the Netsuite documentation that deals with passing sublist values between records

Answer (score 1):

For starters I would want to see the Client Script.

One option would be to only pass the Invoice Record ID and Type. Then you can create a Suitelet to be used as a proxy and get the sublist data by a saved search.
Something to keep in mind is that if the sublist is very very long you may reach a execution timeout so you may want to consider triggering a MapReduce script to populate the sublist again you would pass it the recType and ID of the invoice and vendor bill and then use a saved search to get the data.

There are other approaches but I would need to see the client script.